# AJAX success callback only carrying out first function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a simple form submission that upon success I've got an alert and a call to clear the form. I do get the alert, the info gets successfully added to the database, but the second call--for the form to clear, is not being carried out. I'm sure it's something simple I'm doing wrong, but I can't figure it out.

```
$('#contact_submit').click(function(e){
                if ($("#submit_form_contact").valid()) {


                    var post_data = {
                        "name" : $('#name').val(),
                        "email" : $('#email').val(),
                        "inquiry" : $('#inquiry_dropdown option:selected').text(),
                        "message" : $('#message').val()
                    };


                    $.ajax({  
                      type: "POST",  
                      url: "process-contact.php",  
                      data: post_data,  
                      success: function(data) {  
                        alert("Thank you for contacting us.");
                        $('#submit_form_contact').reset();
                      }  
                    });

                    e.preventDefault();

                }
```

Also, the submit button is just a button, not a submit input. Is it necessary to preventDefault()? I'm new at this.

Comment: Try adding `console.log($('#submit_form_contact'));` between the alert and the reset.  Look in the log there should be a `>` you can click on to expand the object. See if it looks like a form object and has a reset method. If it doesn't have a reset() method or a null or undefined is being pushed on the log, you have identified the problem.

Comment: By "just a button" do you mean `<button>`, `<button type="button">`, or something else?

Comment: Ah! Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'reset'. I don't completely understand though--it's the form's ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have a `.reset()` method.

Do this instead:

```
$('#submit_form_contact')[0].reset();
```

This grabs the first DOM element, and invokes the native `.reset()`. If there's any chance the form won't be found, then test for the element.

```
var f = $('#submit_form_contact')[0];

if (f)
    f.reset();
```

---

And of course you don't really need jQuery to get an element by ID, especially if you're not going to use any jQuery methods.

```
var f = document.getElementbyId('submit_form_contact');

if (f)
    f.reset();
```

---

Another alternative would be to set the submit button as the `context:` of the ajax call, then use its `form` property.

```
                $.ajax({  
                  context: this,
                  type: "POST",  
                  url: "process-contact.php",  
                  data: post_data,  
                  success: function(data) {  
                    alert("Thank you for contacting us.");
                    this.form.reset();
                  }  
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

this line can be used too

```
$("#submit_form_contact").trigger('reset');
```